# Dynamic Table name being recognised as a column name

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql

Any reason why the dynamic schema and table name in the below script is being recognised as a column name? IF i hard code in the schema and table names outside of the dynamic script the function executes no issues.

Error = Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
Invalid column name '55_Dataset'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
Invalid column name 'EPAPRIORITY'.
repeated for each iteration

Table example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyRQ5.jpg)

```
DECLARE @Counter INT;
DECLARE @DATASET nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @STATE nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @Counter = 1;

WHILE @Counter <= 10

BEGIN

SET @DATASET = (Select [DATASET] FROM [xxx].[dbo].[EPA_Geocoding_Progress] Where [INT] = @Counter)
SET @STATE = (Select [STATE] FROM [xxx].[dbo].[EPA_Geocoding_Progress] Where [INT] = @Counter)
SET @sql = '
UPDATE [xxx].[dbo].[EPA_Geocoding_Progress] 
Set [Geocoded] = (Select COUNT (*) FROM [xxx].[' + @STATE + '].[' + @DATASET + '])
Where [STATE] =  [' + @STATE + '] AND [DATASET] = [' + @DATASET + ']'
exec sp_executesql @sql;

SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;


END
```

Comment: Can you post the true message that is encountered ? and tag the database you are using ?

Comment: Make sure that your state and dataset variable is correctly generated with QUOTENAME function and remove the brackes from your literal expression. If you have a State with a name that includes a "]" then it won't be correctly interpreted as is.

Answer (score -1):

#### SQL server Version

it seems no problem

check `;` before Set

i try it:

```
CREATE TABLE EPA_Geocoding_Progress(
    Geocoded  int
);

CREATE TABLE TEST(
    ID  int
);
```

---

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
,@STATE nvarchar(max) = 'dbo'
,@DATASET nvarchar(max) = 'test' 
Set @sql = '
UPDATE [dbo].[EPA_Geocoding_Progress] 
Set [Geocoded] = (Select COUNT (*) FROM [' + @STATE + '].[' + @DATASET + '])'
select @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql; -- Run Success
```

---

[DEMO SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dfc27/4/0)

Answer (score -1):

If you will code with print like this:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @STATE varchar(50)
declare @DATASET varchar(50)
set @STATE = 'dbo'
set @DATASET = 'test'
Set @sql = '
UPDATE [dbo].[EPA_Geocoding_Progress] 
Set [Geocoded] = (Select COUNT (*) FROM [' + @STATE + '].[' + @DATASET + '])'
   print @sql;
```

you will see what's wrong.